# fopen failed while writing into an external SDcard in Android native code

Tags: android, android-external-storage

When I am trying to write into external SDcard from android native code, I am getting permission denied in fopen.

```
mFp = fopen("/storage/extSdCard/Output/test.txt", "wb");
```

if I print strerror(errno) it gives ->

```
fopen(/storage/extSdCard/Output/test.txt) failed: Permission denied
```

Please note that I have also given the permissions in my Application manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
....
</manifest>
```

and also :

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
```

is returing true.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the external storage is an external card that is inserted or the sdcard that comes with the device.If it is an sdcard that comes with the device itself try your path as "/mnt/drive_path" and check if you native method is able to write to your storage.

Comment: Dear vembutech, as I have already mentioned, its not the internal memory/ sdcard. Its the sdcard that is inserted in the ext memory slot. I am not able to write into that external storage. I have also verified from the adb shell, path is correct and exactly where I want to write.